# php var doesn't get a value after a function call

Tags: php, sql

I am currently working on an web application that manage networks data base.
I just added a sort function on a table for users.

To sum up a user fill some checkbox with differents informations then a sql query is executed and displayed on the web page.

This is working perfectly, you can make multiple search in a row there isnt any probleme.
But if you use the sort function that i created, the table is displayed sorted (on click on column's header) as it shall be, you can sort the same initial query multiple times there isnt any problems but then if you want to fill once again the checkboxes the new query will be false.
In fact somes $var which was perfectly assigned before don't take new values it just stay empty.
EDIT : just tried multiple times to run new search after sorting sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't O:

but if you log out and log in again you can make a search.

Here is my code, any advices are welcome.

```
elseif(isset($_POST['SubmitQuery'])){ //this is to make the request in terms of what you as been writed in the form // 
    if (isset($_SESSION['admin_current_query']) && isset($_POST['TRIE'])) { // note : trie means sort in english. if this test is true then it execute the following code and jump to the display.php file.
        $sql = $_SESSION['admin_current_query'];
        $fields = $_SESSION['fields'];
        $fields_ut = $_SESSION['fields_ut'];
    } else {
        unset($_SESSION['admin_current_query']);
        echo "debug: unset admin query\n";
        if (in_array('box_cc_vlan', $_POST))
        {
            unset($_POST[array_search("box_cc_vlan", $_POST)]);
            $vlan_list = array();
        }

        extract($_POST); //             
        $fields = CheckboxString('box_cc_'); // here are my var from the form this is this field that will become empty once you used the sort function.
        $fields_ut = CheckboxString('box_ut_');
        $fieldsString = ','.$fields; // coma added for SQL query
        if(usertrackingUse)
            $fields_utString = $fields_ut; // note this field stay empty too if sort function has been used
```

Here is my sort function.

```
if(!isset($_POST['TRIE'])){
    unset($_SESSION['CustomTrie']);
    $_SESSION['sens'] = 0;
}

if(isset($_POST['TRIE'])){// sort function 
    $_SESSION['sens'] = !$_SESSION['sens'];// 1 or 0 equal toi ASC or DESC
    $sql = $_SESSION['admin_current_query'];// current sql query to modify
    $request = sprintf('%s',$_POST['cc1']);// getting the value of a hidden in a form
    if ($_SESSION['sens'] == 1){ //  direction 
        $request .= " ASC,";
        $_SESSION['CustomTrie'] = sprintf('%s',$request) . sprintf('%s', $_SESSION['CustomTrie']);

        $request2  = sprintf('%s', $_SESSION['CustomTrie']);
        $sql .= " ORDER BY $request2  cc_equip_res ASC , cc_port ASC, cc_date ASC";
    } else {
        $request .= " DESC,";
        $_SESSION['CustomTrie'] = sprintf('%s',$request) . sprintf('%s', $_SESSION['CustomTrie']);

        $request2  = sprintf('%s', $_SESSION['CustomTrie']);
        $sql .= " ORDER BY $request2  cc_equip_res ASC , cc_port ASC, cc_date ASC";
    }
    unset($_POST['TRIE']);// unset TRIE to not infinite loop
}
```

If anyone got an idea about what could cause such behaviour ... ?

thanks you for your consideration.

Comment: search vs research? You'd probably mean **search**, and why use `sprintf()`? seems no need.

Comment: Yea sorry i mean search, sprintf is needed on a $_session because otherway if you write for example : $sql .= $_SESSION['CustomTrie']; and then you want it to be executed (x= mysql_query($sql)); it wont work, I don't know why exactly.

Comment: Well, it depends on your contents in the session variable. You didn't escape the variable, which may lead to SQL Injection. Plus, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. Use MySQLi / PDO instead

Answer (score 0):

(don't fortget in your next posts)

Could we have a look at the form page ?
And for isset, you can put more than one parameter.

Ex:

```
if(isset($_POST['a']) && isset($_POST['b']))
[...]
```

is the same as:

```
if(isset($_POST['a'], $_POST['b']))
[...]
```